# Copy to Oracle using SQL Developer failed in case of migrating Postgres database to oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-migration

I tried these options first

- download JDBC driver for Postgres from http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html
- in SQL Developer go to `Tools → Preferences, Database → Third Party JDBC Drivers` and add the jar file. (see
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/migration/jdbc-migration-1923524.html for step by step example)
- now just make a new Database Connection and instead of Oracle, select PostgreSQL tab

And this is all fine. I can see tables and views etc in Oracle SQL developer, but when I select any of the tables from PostgreSQL and right click on table name and select "Copy to Oracle", nothing happens

According to this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/migration.htm#RPTUG45388 I should get a prompt to choose database.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or is it even possible to copy PostgreSQL tables to Oracle using SQL developer?

Comment: Open the log panel, see any errors or messages?

Comment: You can also try dragging and dropping a table from Postgresql to an Oracle connection to start a copy

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I tried dragging and dropping a table from Postgre to Oracle and i got this error "1 tables failed.
   Failed to create Table <table name> Rollback successful
       ERROR: syntax error at or near "`" "

Comment: the very little work we did here was based on greenplum's implementation of postgres...we don't officially support postgresql migrations in SQL Developer, but we can still help, feel free to email me at jeff.d.smith@oracle.com